# What linux command-line tool extracts all character substrings from the beginning of the string?

Tags: linux, string, command-line

I have a file with ~100K newline delimited strings with no spaces. The length of string varies from 2 to 10. My task is to process every line and output on the same line all substrings starting from the beginning. For example:

The input string is

```
ABCDEF
```

The expected output is

```
A AB ABC ABCD ABCDE ABCDEF
```

The order of substrings in output is not important.

It is easy to write a Python script but I am curious whether is is possible with plain Linux command-line tools.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I can get you started.
Count the characters:

```
# printf ABCDEF|wc -m
6
```

Cut them out:

```
# echo ABCDEF|cut -c 1-1
A
# echo ABCDEF|cut -c 1-2
AB
```

Supposing you count bash programming as plain linux command line tools, you can construct a loop using the count and replace the last range argument.

Answer (score 1):

Just added a loop to @Gary Armstrong's answer with pretty output(`tr`) as an additional step.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=ABCDEF 
for (( i=1; i<=${#var}; i++ )); do
echo -n "$var"|cut -c 1-${i}|tr "\n" " "
done
```

output:-

```
A AB ABC ABCD ABCDE ABCDEF
```

Answer (score 0):

It was surprisingly easy to do with awk, with which I have very limited experience.

```
{
for ( i = 1 ; i <= length($0) ; i++ )
 if ( i < length($0) )
  print "%s\t", substr($0,1,i)
 else
  printf "%s\n", $0
}
```

The "for" loop goes over all lengths from the string and calls the substr() function for each index value. The only special case is the last iteration - the whole string must be returned. This is to avoid a trailing tab at the end of the line.